# What would be a good use case for Solr's LengthFilterFactory?

Tags: solr

I've got a database holding musical works, and an example of a title could be "I See A Soul".

As it is right now, I'm indexing musical works using a field which is configured with a LengthFilterFactory to filter out words less than 2 characters and more than 255 characters. This, of course, filters out "I" and "A" in "I See A Soul" so the resulting indexed document would hold the title "See Soul". Consequently, this doesn't produce the desired results as users can't search for "I See A Soul". So, I'm removing the LengthFilterFactory.

However, I'm curious : In what situations would it be a good idea to strip out words of certain lengths?

Comment: You should take a look at CommonGramsFilterFactory - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you can apply the same filter to the query too. 
So that if the user search for "I see a soul" or "see a soul" or "u see w soul" he will still find the same result.

another idea could be that if you have a requirement that does not allow the user to search until they type at least 3 letters (like an autocomplete function for example), you may not want to index the word less than 3 letters as they will not be searched against anyway.